# Angular 2. Property is private and only accessible within class

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to compile an angular 2 app using AOT. In my project I'm using angular-2-json-schema-form and it's causing errors like this:

> Property is private and only accessible within class

when compiling my app.

I think that problem is in TypeScript. Somebody help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Post your code if you expect help

Comment: you're accessing a `private` field in a template. Don't do that.

Comment: I'm not accessing a private field in template. I'm just using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-json-schema-form and all problems in it

Comment: @drewmoore, is there some tsconfig property which can disable such typescript behavior?

Comment: @Noob no - it's not tsc that's throwing, it's ngc, and this is by design. If the error is coming out of that library, it should be filed as a bug against their repo.

Comment: The library readme says it is a personal proof of concept project, I wouldn't suggest using it in production if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

Per this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6108), it's because prod builds use Ahead of Time compilation by default. You can work around it by turning off AOT, or by using public properties.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable problem is that you have in a component.html some like {{myService.value}} or you have a enum and use directy in your component.html (e.g. .

If you are using myService.value, use a getter

```
get value(){
   return myService.value;
}
//in your .html
{{value}}
```

If your problem is because you're using an enum, declare a variable

```
IEnum=Enum

//in your .html
<div *ngIf="value==IEnum.Case1">
```